Introductory texts about the basics of currencies and finance - ideally various perspectives (not just neoclassical)
I am trying to understand de-dollarisation as someone starting to read up on international relations on my own i.e. I'm not in college anymore and I don't have a background in economics.
The first article that I picked up makes clear that I need technical knowledge of demand and supply of a currency, interest rates, bonds of different kinds, financial products, current account deficits etc. Such technical knowledge I don't yet have.
However I don't want merely the standard neoclassical perspective - although I won't refuse to learn it. It would be best if some of the introductory texts take into account debates in political economy or at least have a keen awareness of political factors. For example, from my limited understanding: you can use familiar textbook graphs to predict that printing large amounts of a currency will lead to inflation, but the fact that QE in America did not create that dreaded hyperinflation for many years needs a deeper explanation beyond simple graphs.
Please recommend some texts that can help me, or offer whatever guidance you can relative to my goal. Thanks!

The simple graphs will show you that the increased money supply from the Fed did not translate into larger monetary aggregates. The rest is just details. De-dollarization is largely a myth so far. It also has nothing to do with QE.
